# Create a WebView without xml

Tags: android, view

For some reason (like loading and don't think too long) i need to create by code a web view and show it after 2s not immediately i have a pointer to my context. i have a id for my relative layout.

I have try some code but i see nothing i don't know if it's the position who is bad or the view.

So what is the good way to make a simple web View who match_parent without any XML? any sample somewhere?

what i have try (i know it's not in match parent it's a test or see the limite of the view if she exist but i see nothing)

```
web = new WebView(context);
web.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200, 200));
web.setX(400);
web.setY(400);
web.bringToFront();
```

My xml the thing i didn't find is how to say i add my webview in this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main" >    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml of the page you are trying to add it to?

Comment: edited question to add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add it to your root view. It's created but floating around unattached to any view.

```
RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

WebView web = new WebView(context);
web.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

main.addView(web); // <--- Key line
```

Comment: For some reason i didn't find, my RelativeLayout is equal to null*

Comment: Put this in your activity: `Relativelayout main;`, then populate it in your `onCreate()`: `main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);` after you did `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout.xml)`, then reference it wherever you are doing the webview stuff. Post your full activity if you want more help.

Comment: i have find a way i just don't use the findviewbyId in the right context now it's work thank

Comment: Just to be sure when i need to stop this view i nedd this? 
layout.removeView(web); or something else? and any way to call my webview destructor?

Comment: Yes `removeView` works to remove it. No need to explicitly call the destructor. Although, if I were you, I would not create and destroy the view like this, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. You can just hide it using `visibility` if that is your goal.

Comment: I will show multiple thing in a webview and with visibility i have load time, i will still show my first webview when i create the second load contenu and after close the first one and show the seconde one. I think create dynamicly a view is a good way to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
final WebView wv = new WebView(main);
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mainLayout.addView(wv);
        LayoutParams params = wv.getLayoutParams();
        // Edit those params as you need, then call
        wv.setLayoutParams(params);
    }   

}.execute();
```